# Swift, Firebase. Check if a users, childs value exists

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my game you, first have to login, then you have to choose a team name, which gets stored in my firebase database, under the players UID, and when the player has entered his team name, I want to check if it is already taken, or the player is good to go.

```
let rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
rootRef.queryOrderedByChild("teamName").queryEqualToValue("Bob fc").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

    if (snapshot.value is NSNull) {
        print("Name is not in use")
    } else {
        print("Name is in use")
    }   
})
```

My data tree:

```
{
    "users" : {
        "pbXvXYOKmJQqwSQZ9IlBykG7x1P2" : {
             "teamName" : "Bob fc"
        }
    }
}
```

My database rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't print anything, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are querying your root ref. You should query the /users node instead,

Comment: Should I just do rootRef.child("users").queryOrdere... then?

Comment: Sure. I threw out an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are querying your root ref. You should query the /users node instead

```
let rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
let usersRef = rootRef.childByAppendingPath("users")
usersRef.queryOrderedBy....
```

You can shorten that up but I used the verbose model for clarity.

As a side note, with Firebase 3.x, the default is to only allow authenticated users to read and write. This is accomplished through Rules in the Realtime Database section.

If you want to test your code without authenticating, change your Rules to this

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

PLEASE NOTE: This opens up your data to ANYONE that wants to read it, but if you are just learning or testing an app it makes it a bit more convenient.

Comment: It still doesn't print anything -.-

Comment: @Benja0906 if it prints nothing then the block is not called at all or you are being denied access. That would indicate that your Firebase reference is not correct or more likely you are not authenticated when trying to read. In Firebase 3.x, the default is to only allow authenticated users to read and write. Check the rules in the Firebase console.

Comment: I think u are right, it doesn't seem like it is checking at all, I tried to just print a random string inside the observer, and it never got printed. I edited my question, and wrote down my database rules, maybe something is wrong with them, I don't really have any knowledge about how to properly write the rules.

Comment: @Benja0906 Ah, yep - now there's your problem. See my updated answer - you can copy/paste the rules I wrote to temporarily fix the issue.